# FirstFactorial Javascript - Why am I receiving an undefined output?

Tags: javascript

I am currently learning JavaScript and so I tried to make a piece of code that 
    would calculate and output the first factorials for numbers 1-18.

Here is my code:

```js
  function FirstFactorial(num) {

x = num ;
y = 1 ;
n = 0 ;
  
while (num > 0 && y > 0) {
  if (x === 0) {
    console.log(y) ;
  }
  x -= 1 ;
  y = num * x ;
  n += y ;

}



return FirstFactorial; 
     
}

  

var x = 17 ;

FirstFactorial(x);

while (x > 1) {
  x -= 1 ;
  FirstFactorial(x);
}
```

When I try to output this it returns 'undefined'. Anyone know why?

Help would be deeply appreciated as I am still learning.

Comment: at least you need to call the function **with** parameters again.

Comment: I don't see any output.

Comment: you need to console.log() it or something to see. and by the way where are you outputting the values? and why are you returning the Function itself??

Comment: @manishkumar I have put the console.log inside the function

Comment: @melpomene It gives this if you run it on a compiler "=> undefined"

Comment: @poisonishere No, it doesn't.

Comment: @melpomene Mind showing me what you receive?                                                        http://prntscr.com/gd7fy6

Comment: @poisonishere I already told you, your code produces no output.

Comment: @melpomene Why is that?

Comment: @poisonishere Because the only part that could produce output (`console.log(y)`) is guarded by an `if (x == 0)` condition. But if `x` is 0, then `y = num * x` is also 0, in which case the loop condition `... && y > 0` is false, so we would've left the loop in the previous iteration. Therefore the `console.log` is unreachable.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you were trying to do, but here is a function for getting factorials:

```
function factorial(num) {
// create a value, that will hold the end result
var returnValue = 1;
for(var i = num; i > 0; i++) {
// decrement i a required amount of time and multiply returnValue by i
returnValue *= i;
}

return returnValue;
}
```

This one works too:

```
function factorial(num) {
if (num == 0) {
return 1;
} else return num*factorial(num-1);
}
```

To write multiple factorials, just add another loop or use this function:

```
function firstFactorial(num) {
if (num == 0) {
console.log(1)
return 1; 
} else {
var x = num*factorial(num-1);
console.log(x);
return x;
}
```

---- How the last code works

I guess you didn't have any problem understanding all the parts of the code. But the way it is looping is by calling the same function.
Take a look at this code:

```
function a() { 
a()
}
```

The function calls itself inside itself... so we are going to enter an endless loop. However, we can also use the loop for our purposes.

In the factorial code we are going with the loop downwards. From the highest number to the lowest until 0.

If we want to find the factorial of 3 this will be:
factorial(3) = 3*factorial(2) = 3*2*factorial(1) = 3*2*1*factorial(0) = 3*2*1*1

```
var x = num*factorial(num-1);
```

This is the code that makes the loop. We are calling the same function but with num decremented (num-1).

If (num-1) is equal to zero, loop stops, because we return a value and do not call the function again. If it is not zero, we call the function with an even lower value.

Comment: I tried to edit it with console.logs rather than returning it, it gave an error, should I keep it the same?

Comment: Yup, return is required in the second factorial code. However, you can have both console.log() and return. I guess my last example should work properly.

Comment: Hi man, this is effective however I would like to ask you a question. I tried understanding a bit of the code and most of it was straight forward, however I didn't understand how it kept going, was there a loop?                 I'd like it if you could tell me what you did on every line (comment).

Comment: I assume we are talking about the last example.

Comment: Yes we are. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you try printing the values with the below code

```js
function FirstFactorial(num) {
console.log(num)
var x = num ;
var y = 1 ;
var n = 0 ;
  console.log(x,y,n) 
while (num > 0 && y > 0) {
console.log(x,y,n)  
if (x === 0) {
    console.log(y) ;
  }

  x -= 1 ;
  y = num * x ;
  n += y ;

}       
}
FirstFactorial(5)
```

> it never reaches the condition where x=0. because when x=0,y-0 and while loops breaks. This code is pretty much useless then. I can enhance the code for you if you want but...

A simple way to find factorial is through recursion

```js
function fact(x) {
   if(x==0) {
      return 1;
   }
   return x * fact(x-1);
}
console.log(fact(10))
```

you can put break points to get your result.